# Pass query silently when url match

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to pass a query to the url bar when the url meets a certain criteria.

For example:

When I change site language to Dutch, we end up with https://www.example.com/nl

However, when we change site language to Dutch, we need to pass a query to the url bar "?lang=nl". We have a component that require this query to be passed.

However, we don't want that query to be visible in the url bar. It should pass silently.

Is it possible to do this? I am using Wordpress.

I have tried

```
<?php

$urls = array(
         'http://www.example.com',
         'http://www.example.com/nl/'
        );

$query = 'lang=nl';

foreach($urls as &$url) {
   $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
   if ($parsedUrl['path'] == null) {
      $url .= '/';
   }
   $separator = ($parsedUrl['query'] == NULL) ? '?' : '&';
   $url .= $separator . $query;
}
```

But this shows the query in the url bar and the query is passed for all $urls.

Comment: Why would you need `?lang=nl`, if you have `/nl` at the start of the URL already? Isn’t the latter supposed to be your language determining parameter already? _“However, we don't want that query to be visible in the url bar. It should pass silently.”_ - then you don’t want a GET parameter in the first place, those are always visible. The things that “pass silently”, are either _farts_, or forms with method=post.

Comment: ?lang=nl ensures that a component also loads in Dutch. If I don't pass that query, a certain component on the page doesn't show in Dutch. It's a third party component.

Comment: Then try _setting_ `$_GET['lang'] = 'nl'`, based on the `/nl` from the URL, first thing in your script – then anything included later will have access to that, as if it had been an _actual_ query string parameter in the first place. (If that does not work, then that component probably accesses the GET parameters in a different way - it might use $_REQUEST, or fish it out of the query string contained in $_SERVER - either way, I’d try and figure out which one exactly it is, then you should be able to set that yourself somehow, without needing a _real_ GET parameter in the HTTP request.)